# API key limitations and email verification

Tags: evernote

I've recently found out that, if Evernote's user does not verify his email address, all requests to Evernote API is not working. But I didn't find any ways to request email verification in Evernote's web interface, looks like the proposal to verify email appears randomly ? Are there any ways to request email verification from the user ?

Comment: Could you provide what you are trying to do and what error you've got? Code snippets and stack trace will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask users to change their email address via [the page on the web](https://www.evernote.com/secure/SecuritySettings.action), which will send them a verification email and verify their address.